# How to change icons (fontawesome icons) on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change icon when user hover over it. I did find a similar question on StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681658/change-fontawesome-icon-with-text-on-hover) but when I tried this it is not that effective. When I put the cursor over its screen starts lagging. So I am trying to know is there any better way to do this using javascript.

This is my code

> index.html

```
<li class="nav-item hide-on-mb icon-box">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
        <i class="fas fa-bars menu"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times cross"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

> main.css

```
.icon-box {
        .cross {
            display: none;
        }
        :hover .menu {
            display: none;
        }
        :hover .cross {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using plain `css` or `scss`?

Comment: @AdityaSrivast don't automatically create snippet of code, his code is SASS not CSS. So either convert it to a CSS code or simply don't create a non-runnable snippet

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry i forgot to change that yes the code is in scss.

Comment: it's OK to use SASS, there  is no issue. I am commenting to the person who did the wrong edit to create the snippet (surprisingly both of you have the same name ..)

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah! I missed it! Thanks for pointing out. Will take care

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use onmouseover and onmouseout events:

```
<i class="fas fa-times cross" onmouseover="this.className = 'fas fa-times cross'"; onmouseout="this.className='whatever the other class name is'" ></i>
```

Comment: it still lags though but better than other options.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without changing the class on the `<i>` element - by being aware of the way the FA icons are implemented - they are ::before pseudo-elements that can change on the hover.

Simply by knowing the Unicode of each icon - you can set the default state and then change on hover - all with css.

```css
.icon-box { 
 list-style: none;
}

.icon-box i::before{
  content: "\f0c9";
  font-size: 24px;
}

.icon-box:hover i::before{
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>Hover over the icon.... </p>

<ul>
<li class="nav-item hide-on-mb icon-box">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
   <i class="fas"></i>
  </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
.icon-box {
    .cross {
        display: none;

        &:hover {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    .menu {
        display: none;

        &:hover {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

[Pseudo class](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) declarations should come after the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following example to know how to change icon on hover

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.fa-facebook
{
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from { 
    opacity: 1; 
  }
  to { 
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fa-car").mouseover(function(){
    $(".fa-car").css({"opacity":"0","position":"absolute"});
 $(".fa-facebook").css({"opacity": "1","position":"absolute", "animation-name": "fadeIn","animation-delay":"0.5s"});
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fa-facebook").mouseover(function(){
    $(".fa-car").css({"opacity": "1","position":"absolute","animation-name": "fadeIn","animation-delay":"0.5s"});
    $(".fa-facebook").css({"opacity":"0","position":"absolute"});
 
  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is done by using animation and jquery. Icon will only change when hover over it